# Override an email address coming from the organizational Outlook address book

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, address-book

So, I work in an educational organization which uses Outlook, with the mail hosted by Microsoft.  I run the desktop app (version 2210), and as is typical we have a large list of users in the organizational address book.  I regularly communicate with Bob, and their email in the organizational address book is bob@organization.org.  Unfortunately because of how we've evolved Bob generally uses an email address for one of our associated entities, bob@entity.org.  As a result every time I send an email to share an encrypted document, it defaults to the "official" email address, and when it gets forwarded to bob@entity.org they end up unable to access the encrypted email.  I actually have a few other folks like this, Eunice, Shecky, etc.

Can I somehow tell my desktop installation, or even better my entire user account, to ignore the centrally-distributed bob@organization.org address and use the actually useful one, bob@entity.org?  I've tried setting up contacts but it makes no difference.

Comment: Set up a different account and use that. Outlook allows multiple accounts including accounts in addition to Exchange.

Comment: Wait, what, for me?  I still want to use all of the >other< contacts associated with the address book.  Part of the problem is I'm sending emails to several people and miss that I've got the wrong address defaulting for Bob.

Comment: I am not sure otherwise how you will do that.

Comment: Why not configure Bob's two accounts in a profile in Outlook?

Comment: It has been a while and I am writing to see how things are going on with this issue. Have you had a chance to check the replies provided? Any update would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

At this point I have given up and put in place a rule which will a) delay mailing of any email sent to the bad address so they move into my Outbox, b) place a copy of the email in my Inbox so I know I got the wrong email, and then c) I can resend the email and delete the copy with the bad emails from my Outbox.  It's lame but it's the only workaround I've come up with.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that the old email address is still valid on our domain, but this person works in a spinoff subentity and thus has another email address which they use more consistently and to which they get emails forwarded.  As a result emails with encrypted content are received in an inbox where they can't be opened.  There's no institutional fix for this, unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks, @VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle.  I've basically given up on this, but yeah, separate domain, separate email system.  The email address they're using isn't the problem, just my inability to override their email on our system being the default used by Outlook.